# How to acces index [i-1] at the first iteration of a FOR loop [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe with various columns, with the header: "Temperatura", "Inc_t", "t".

Edit: As requested, what follows is the dataframe used and the previous segment of code, for context:

```py
       Temperatura    Date       
    1        24.72        2.3        
    2        25.76        4.6        
    3        25.42        7.0        
    4        40.31        9.3        
    5        26.21       15.6
    6        26.59       17.9
   ...                         #It has a total of 4k rows
```

```py
df=pd.real_excel(r'/home/.../CampExt_HP.xlsx')
T0=0

from scipy import stats
L=df.shape[0]
j=df.shape[1]
for i in range(1,L+1):
  df["Inc_t"]=df["Fecha"].diff() 

dfn=df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df['Temperatura']))<4)] #Eliminated outliers from dataframe
L=dfn.shape[0]
j=dfn.shape[1]

fcm=np.zeros(L+1)
Mm=np.zeros(L+1)
M=np.asarray(Mm)

dfn["t"]=pd.Series([0 for i in range(len(dfn.index))],index=dfn.index)
```

Relevant snippet of code:

```
M[0]=dfn["Inc_t"][0]*(dfn["Temperatura"][0]-T0) #Sidenote: This line works fine 

for i in range(1,L+1):
    M[i]=dfn["Inc_t"][i]*(dfn["Temperatura"][i]-T0)
    M[i]=M[i-1]+M[i]
    dfn["t"][i]=dfn["t"][i-1]+dfn["Inc_t"][i]
```

Notes for context:

- I previously defined dfn as a new dataframe, because when I was
  modifying the original dataframe (df) by re-defining it with extra
  columns, it did not register the changes being made.
- L is the number of rows in my dataframe.

When I execute this, I obtain the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Metodo6.py", line 70, in <module>
 M[i]=dfn["Inc_t"][i]*(dfn["Temperatura"[i]-T0)
 File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
 result = self.index.get_value(self,key)
 File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4404, in get_value
 return self._engine.get_value(s,k,tz=getattr(series.dtype,"tz",None))
 File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
 File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
 File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
 File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
 File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1005, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 4692
```

I saw in other similar posts that this has to do with the index 'i-1' not being established in the FOR loop, but I had inicialised it by defining M[0].

I am pretty new to Python, so I expect that the answer is probably obvious to most users.
Any pointers would be really helpful! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace so we can see where the error is coming from? Also, more information about dfn and the other variables you use would help us help you. See this post on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you change the for loop to `range(1,L)` does that fix the issue?

Comment: Hi, I edited the post to include a wider portion of code and the full error.
Also, no, changing the range to (1,L) does not seem to do the trick  @MichaelDelgado

Comment: are you sure? you can't do `df[col][len(df)]` - you'll get this KeyError. It looks to me like this is what's happening.

Comment: It worked at last. Your solution was correct. The problem is that I had not reset the indexing after applying outlier deletion. Thanks!
If you post your solution as answer, I can accept it, in case anyone gets the same problem in future!

Comment: How can I then add the missing element M[L]?

Comment: It's not missing. Python is 0-indexed, so you always use indices [0, length - 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## IndexError bug

Because python is 0-indexed, iterating over any collection `c` must use indices in the range `[0, len(c) - 1]`. Note that for-loops frequently loop over python [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#range) objects, which iterate over all elements *up to but not including* the stop argument, so `for i in range(0, len(c))` will still only reference elements in `[0, len(c)-1]`.

To loop over a collection while referencing the current element and a prior element, you can set the initial condition for `result[0]`, then iterate over `range(1, len(c))`.

The issue appears to be in your indices in your for loop. Because `L=dfn.shape[0]`, the last iteration of your for loop, which iterates over `range(1, L+1)`, references element `len(dfn)`, which causes an index error.

## Performance

Separately, it looks like you're using for loops to carry out some pretty standard pandas operations. Check out this section in the pandas docs on [vectorized operations with pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#vectorized-operations-and-label-alignment-with-series) (this applies to operations on individual columns of a DataFrame as well).

In your case, the initialization and first line of the for loop:

```py
M[0]=dfn["Inc_t"][0]*(dfn["Temperatura"][0]-T0) #Sidenote: This line works fine 

for i in range(1,L):
    M[i]=dfn["Inc_t"][i]*(dfn["Temperatura"][i]-T0)
```

can (and should) be replaced with a single, much faster line:

```py
M = dfn["Inc_t"] * (dfn["Temperatura"] - T0)
```

Looks like the 2nd and 3rd lines of your loop are computing a cumulative sum:

```py
for i in range(1, L):
    M[i]=M[i-1]+M[i]
```

This can be replaced with [pandas.Series.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```py
M = M.cumsum()
```

Trying to use vectorized operators like this wherever possible will significantly speed up your code, since pandas operators (generally) are backed by optimized numpy operators in C, which are much faster than for-loops in pure python.

Answer (score 0):

could try changing your for loop to something like;

```
for i, j in zip(df.index[:-1], df.index[1:]):
    print(i, j)
```

Comment: I tried it. I get: IndexError: too many indices for array. But thanks for the input!

Comment: this loops over the indexes, how are you using them? with .iloc or .loc?

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve the problem by reseting the indexes and changing the loop range to 1:L. Thanks for the help!